# Why cordova resources is generating cropped splash images

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I create my splash/icon images with Photoshop. And tried to generate the icon and splash with `ionic cordova resources android`

**Result:**

Icons well created but the splashes where **cropped** (lost some parts of the original image). I'm wondering why!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the icon will always be a square so the `resources` command just has to resize the 1024x1024px square you provide. The splash image on the other side is also provided as a square of 2732x2732px but it will never be used as a square. Every splash-screen is a rectangle so the image has to be cut to the right size.

This is why the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/) mention that you should put the actual artwork of your splashscreen into a square of 1200x1200px so only the background is cut of. [Here](https://code.ionicframework.com/resources/splash.psd) is a .psd template you can use to create your splash image.